# «Не что иное, как» — какова синтаксическая роль в предложении?

Tags: синтаксис, члены-предложения

"Честолюбие есть не что иное, как жажда власти".

Какой член предложения "как жажда власти"?

Comment: Правка неясна. В названии вопроса указано одно сочетание, а в тексте другое.

Answer (score 4):

[Не что иное, как](http://old-rozental.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=2374) — это местоименное сочетание (неразложимое), выражающее противопоставление. Оно входит в состав именной части составного именного сказуемого (не просто "жажда", а ***жажда власти***).
Это сочетание можно заменить словами *именно, как раз, по сути*, оно близко по смыслу и употреблению к [уточняющим частицам](https://russky.info/ru/grammar/prepositions).
**С союзом "а"** (он бы тогда предшествовал сочетанию) предложение имело бы такой вид (автоматически "как" на "а" заменить невозможно):
*Честолюбие есть жажда власти, **а не что иное.***

Употребляется довольно часто.
*Чрезмерная скромность есть не что иное, как скрытая гордость* (А. М. Шенье); *Характер есть не что иное, как долговременный навык* (Плутарх); *Война есть не что иное, как продолжение государственной политики другими средствами* (К. Клаузевиц).

В словаре Ожегова:
**жажда**
**2.** *перен., чего и с неопр.* Сильное, страстное желание чего-нибудь (высок.).
*Жажда счастья. Жажда знаний. Жажда учиться.*

Comment: "Я хочу начать свой ответ с того, что я не согласен /не согласна с Sharon".  Мне, конечно,  очень приятно такое внимание, но  о несогласии с кем-то лучше писать в комментариях, ответ же следует начинать с ответа. Правильный текст начинается с ЧЕТКОГО ОТВЕТА НА ПОСТАВЛЕННЫЙ АВТОРОМ ВОПРОС, а уж потом вы можете рассказывать всё, что вы знаете о неразложимости сочетаний.  Я же всего-навсего позволила себе сказать,  как грамматически устроен этот  неразложимый, а также неделимый  и нечленимый оборот.  Для любознательных читателей, причем  очень кратко.  Но – нельзя!

Comment: Итак, у вас неразложимое сочетание, а у меня оборот —  и всё это В СОСТАВЕ  СОСТАВНОГО ИМЕННОГО СКАЗУЕМОГО. В чем принципиальная разница, с которой принципиальный человек никак не может согласиться? Итак, поле ответа - для вашего ответа, комментарий - для уточнения  моего мнения (даже не для критики). Или я что-то не так понимаю? Имеете другую точку зрения? Замечательно, напишите нам об этом, мы с удовольствием послушаем, нам будет интересно.

Comment: Здравствуйте, здравствуйте, Sharon! _"Я хочу начать свой ответ с того, что я не согласен /не согласна с Sharon"_ — простите, я так не писала (мне кажется, что мое высказывание не столь категорично). Еще раз извините, и — сделаю так, как Вы говорите (просто мне — не филологу — Ваш ответ показался совершенно непонятным, поэтому я и попыталась дать свое видение).

Comment: Спасибо! Выражение "не что иное, как"  было дано в правиле "Сравнительные обороты" без указания его синтаксической роли, хотя остальные сравнительные конструкции  подчёркнуты как обстоятельства или части сказуемого. Ещё раз большое спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

***Честолюбие есть не что иное, как  жажда власти.***

Оборот речи "не что иное, как" входит в структуру именной части составного именного сказуемого.

Всё сказуемое: ***есть не что иное, как  жажда*** (власти).

Примечания:

1) Вопрос **о включении дополнения** в состав сказуемого — дискуссионный. Решение зависит от содержания текста. Честолюбие не всегда отождествляется с властолюбием.

2) **Формально оборот построен** по образцу противительных конструкций вида НЕ...А,  в которых отрицается один предмет (что) и утверждается другой предмет (жажда). Связь между предметами однородная (сравнить: это не рассказ, а повесть). Таким образом, союз КАК по значению близок к союзу А.

Comment: _Честолюбие не всегда отождествляется с властолюбием._ Совершенно верно. Но честолюбие тем более **никогда** не отождествляется с  просто жаждой — обычной физиологической жаждой (в первом значении).

Comment: Здесь имеется в виду сильное, страстное желание чего-л. (второе значение). ЧЕСТОЛЮБИЕ, -я; ср. Стремление добиться высокого, почётного положения, жажда известности, славы.

Comment: Опять соглашусь: сильное, страстное желание чего-нибудь (именно такую ссылку я и привела в ответе для подтверждения своего мнения). Без включения дополнения в состав сказуемого получается _Честолюбие есть жажда._

Comment: Римма, я не могу понять, что мы обсуждаем. Расскажите лучше, какая у вас погода. У нас была гроза, а  сейчас кончилась.

Comment: Да и правда! У нас — глобальное солнце, море не орёт, бакланы (это мы так называем больших морских чаек) на соседской крыше притихли — интенсивно отдают свое тепло будущим птицам. Тишата́ (тишина + красота)! Три (иногда четыре) раза в день — в любую погоду! — выползаю со своим старым псом на улицу (восемнадцатый год — не фунт изюма). Живем потихоньку. Благо — все здоровы.

Comment: Вот здорово! В какой красоте вы живете, вам надо рассказы об этом писать. Мне кажется, у вас получилось бы. Иногда люди не догадываются, в чем именно они талантливы. Вы попробуйте.

Comment: Ой, да что Вы, Sharon, что Вы! Я ведь технарь по образованию. Куда уж мне? За добрые слова кланяюсь.

Comment: Римма, как будто все писатели Литературный институт заканчивали. У человека любой профессии могут быть способности к художественной речи. Знаете, сейчас ведь многие люди пишут, можно опубликовать свои записки на Прозе.ру, будут у вас читатели.  А мне понравилась ваша картинка, которую вы нарисовали всего-то в двух предложениях. И вы каждый день видите море!  Не многим достается такая возможность. Говорят, оно всё время разное, наверняка есть что-то интересное, о чем можно рассказать. Попробуйте!